# Shiur for kiddush rabba mezonos

Tags: shabbat, shiurim-measurements, kiddush, mezonot-beracha

When we make kiddush rabba with mezonos before having a real meal with bread, is there a shiur for how much mezonos a person should eat in order for it to be yotzei kiddush? Does it matter whether the bread meal is immediately following the mezonos or not?

Answer (score 2):

One must eat a kezayis of mezonos this is from the Magen Avraham.

Comment: Where is that Magen Avraham found?

Comment: See http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=19811 who refers to the MA "The Magen Avraham (273:11) reasons that if the Geonim can accept wine in this context, then it is true of anything made from the grains, which is more meal-like than wine (see Shulchan Aruch, OC 291:5 regarding the laws of seuda shlishit). This is the source of the common practice of having cake for the post-Kiddush "meal.""